# Create linq query to search for contact the same way smartphone will do so

Tags: c#, sql, linq

Let's say that in my database I have the table

```
                **Table Contact**
Id, FirstName, LastName,   Phone,       Email,           DateCreated
1   Tom        Williams    3052548623   tom@gmail.com    2013-12-21 14:51:08
etc...
```

I would like to enable users to search for a contact entering a string. Let's say the user enters:

```
tom       -> TRUE
tom wil   -> TRUE
wil tom   -> TRUE
tom XX    -> FALSE
t w 3 @   -> TRUE
wil 305   -> TRUE
```

*(True means search found customer Tom, False means it did not find it)*

I will be performing this type of search among different tables in my database. It will be nice if I dont have to build the query for a specific table.

---

The approach I am thinking on taking is to split the search string every time I find one or more spaces. Then I will be creating n number of searches and then performing an intersect?

Comment: I am not sure if a smart phone contact search will return a TRUE for wil 305. Which smart phone are you using?

Comment: Samsung galaxy s4. If I search for `wil 305` it will find it. I where not sure how to explain my question. Basically I want to search in all the columns of my table. If a word is not in any of the columns then I will like to return nothing.

Comment: I am getting the gist of it. If you type in Tom 254, are you getting a result in your Samsung Galaxy S4?

Comment: +1 to your answer! No you are right. Perhaps I should change the question title. But hope you get my point. In my case `Tom 254` I will that string to return a match

Comment: Also you want LINQ to ignore case, since C# is case sensitive. The split string approach will not work, since you want every search parameter to be searched in all the fields.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do something like that, assuming you want only search in the string properties (so your samples will work if we considere Phone as a string property).

It's of course doable with numeric properties (but gets more complicated).

A method like that in an helper static class

```
public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> BuildPredicateForFilter<T>(string filterString)
        {
            //first, split search by space, removing white spaces, and putting this to upper case
            var filters = filterString.Split(new []{" "}, StringSplitOptions.RemoveEmptyEntries).Select(m => m.ToUpper());
            var parameter = Expression.Parameter(typeof (T), "m");

            //get string.Contains() method
            var containsMethod = typeof (string).GetMethod("Contains");
            //get string.ToUpper() method
            var toUpperMethod = typeof (string).GetMethod("ToUpper", new Type[]{});
            //find all the string properties of your class
            var properties = typeof(T).GetProperties().Where(m => m.PropertyType == typeof(string));
            //for all the string properties, build a "m.<PropertyName>.ToUpper() expression
            var members = properties.Select(p => Expression.Call(Expression.Property(parameter, p), toUpperMethod));
            Expression orExpression = null;
            //build the expression
            foreach (var filter in filters)
            {
                Expression innerExpression = null;
                foreach (var member in members)
                {
                    innerExpression = innerExpression == null
                        ? (Expression)Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(filter))
                        : Expression.OrElse(innerExpression, Expression.Call(member, containsMethod, Expression.Constant(filter)));
                }
                orExpression = orExpression == null
                    ? innerExpression
                    : Expression.AndAlso(orExpression, innerExpression);
            }
            return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpression, new[]{parameter});

        }
```

usage :

```
var result = <yourSource>.Where(Helper.BuildPredicateForFilter<TableName>("tom XX"));
```

for example, with "tom XX", the orExpression will look like

`((((m.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains("TOM") OrElse 
     m.LastName.ToUpper().Contains("TOM")) OrElse 
     m.Phone.ToUpper().Contains("TOM")) 
     OrElse m.Email.ToUpper().Contains("TOM")) 
AndAlso 
 (((m.FirstName.ToUpper().Contains("XX") OrElse 
    m.LastName.ToUpper().Contains("XX")) OrElse 
    m.Phone.ToUpper().Contains("XX")) OrElse 
    m.Email.ToUpper().Contains("XX")))`

**EDIT**

or you could change the method to

```
public static IQueryable<T> FilterFor(this IQueryable<T> queryable, string filterString) {
  //same
  var predicate = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>(orExpression, new[]{parameter});
  return queryable.Where(predicate);
}
```

then usage would simply be

```
<yourSource>.FilterFor("tom XX");
```

Answer (score 1):

So what we're looking to do here is search through all of the fields in a type for a given value, doing a `Contains` search.  We can write a method to do this.

First we'll need to use a `PredicateBuilder`, as we'll be dynamically generating a number of expressions that we want to OR together.  Here is my definition of a `PredicateBuilder` capable of doing that:

```
public static class PredicateBuilder
{
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> True<T>() { return f => true; }
    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> False<T>() { return f => false; }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> Or<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.OrElse(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }

    public static Expression<Func<T, bool>> And<T>(
        this Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr1,
        Expression<Func<T, bool>> expr2)
    {
        var secondBody = expr2.Body.Replace(expr2.Parameters[0], expr1.Parameters[0]);
        return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, bool>>
              (Expression.AndAlso(expr1.Body, secondBody), expr1.Parameters);
    }
}
```

This uses the following helper method/class to replace all instances of one `Expression` with another:

```
internal class ReplaceVisitor : ExpressionVisitor
{
    private readonly Expression from, to;
    public ReplaceVisitor(Expression from, Expression to)
    {
        this.from = from;
        this.to = to;
    }
    public override Expression Visit(Expression node)
    {
        return node == from ? to : base.Visit(node);
    }
}

public static Expression Replace(this Expression expression,
    Expression searchEx, Expression replaceEx)
{
    return new ReplaceVisitor(searchEx, replaceEx).Visit(expression);
}
```

Another tool that we'll use to solve this problem is a `Compose` method.  It will take one expression, then another expression that takes as input the output of another, and produces a new expression that takes the input of the first and produces the output of the last.

```
public static Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>
    Compose<TFirstParam, TIntermediate, TResult>(
    this Expression<Func<TFirstParam, TIntermediate>> first,
    Expression<Func<TIntermediate, TResult>> second)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(TFirstParam), "param");

    var newFirst = first.Body.Replace(first.Parameters[0], param);
    var newSecond = second.Body.Replace(second.Parameters[0], newFirst);

    return Expression.Lambda<Func<TFirstParam, TResult>>(newSecond, param);
}
```

Thanks to all of these tools, what's left is actually quite straightforward.  We'll accept a query, a string to search for, and a series of selectors, each selecting out a field to search through.  Then we initialize a filter, go through every single selector, use `Compose` to turn each selector into a predicate that performs a `Contains` check on the relevant search text, and then ORs that to the existing filter.

```
public static IQueryable<T> AnyFieldContains<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    string searchText,
    params Expression<Func<T, string>>[] fieldSelectors)
{
    var filter = PredicateBuilder.False<T>();

    foreach (var selector in fieldSelectors)
    {
        filter = filter.Or(selector.Compose(
            value => value.Contains(searchText)));
    }
    return query.Where(filter);
}
```

Now that we have all of this we can split the input that you have, and for each of those expressions we can call this method.  Then you simply need to supply selectors for the fields that need to be searched through:

```
IQueryable<Foo> query = db.Foo;
string searchText = "wil tom";

var searchExpressions = searchText.Split(' ');

foreach (var expression in searchExpressions)
{
    query = query.AnyFieldContains(expression,
        foo => foo.FirstName,
        foo => foo.LastName,
        foo => foo.Phone);
}
var result = query.Any();
```

If you're *really* sure that you want to search *every* field (and I'm not sure if you are, it's likely many tables will have fields that shouldn't be searched, or have fields that will need some sort of work on your end to transform them into an appropriate string worth searching), then you can use reflection to generate all of the selectors, rather than typing out explicitly what you want to have searched.  We can simply create an additional overload such that if no selectors are provided it will use "everything":

```
public static IQueryable<T> AnyFieldContains<T>(
    this IQueryable<T> query,
    string searchText)
{
    return AnyFieldContains(query, searchText,
        typeof(T).GetProperties()
        .Select(prop => CreateSelector<T>(prop))
        .ToArray());
}

private static Expression<Func<T, string>> CreateSelector<T>(PropertyInfo prop)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    Expression body = Expression.Property(param, prop);
    if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(decimal?))
        body = Expression.Call(body, typeof(SqlFunctions)
            .GetMethod("StringConvert", new[] { typeof(decimal?) }));
    else if (prop.PropertyType == typeof(double?))
        body = Expression.Call(body, typeof(SqlFunctions)
            .GetMethod("StringConvert", new[] { typeof(double?) }));
    return Expression.Lambda<Func<T, string>>(body, param);
}
```

Comment: @abhi No it won't, because the last name doesn't contain `XX`

Comment: My bad. This will return FALSE for Tom 305, since the field length will be 2 and it won't evaluate the condition foo.Phone.Contains("305")

Comment: @abhi See edit.  That is of course a tougher problem, but a solvable one.

Comment: @Servy thanks for the help testing it now. Takes me longer to test it than for you to create it. lol

Comment: @TonoNam Well, part of the idea here is that I've built up a number of higher order tools for manipulating expressions.  Once you have those tools the problem is actually quite easy, and I have all of these tools just sitting around, so I just need to copy-paste them here.  Trying to write this all without using these layers of abstraction makes the code quite a lot messier, and *much* more time consuming to develop, as is demonstrated by the other answer here.  My guess is it took him quite a lot longer than the ~90 seconds it took me to write my version.

Comment: @Servy you're right, probably 5 minutes ! But I'm at home, and don't have all my "layers" ;)

Comment: Servy thanks for the help. I get the exception `exception3 = {"The binary operator OrElse is not defined for the types 'System.Boolean' and 'System.Func`2[Micrium.Ucprobe.Licensing.Shared.Data.Customer,System.Boolean]'."}`

Comment: @TonoNam Right, see edit.  There was a small mistake in `PredicateBuilder` that needed fixing.

Comment: @Servy by the way (just a detail), as OP is talking of Database, I think your CreateSelector method, just calling "ToString", will fail for "non string properties" in a linq to entities context.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Do you know of any way of converting any non-string based field to a string?  I notice you just filtered out all non-string fields, but given that several of the fields in the example looked numeric, I doubt that's desirable.

Comment: @Servy Well, in linq to entities, you could do something with numeric fields for example by casting them to nullable double (or nullable decimal) and calling `SqlFunctions.StringConvert`. `ToString` just doesn't work in linq to entities. By the way, I'm absolutely aware that my answer is far far (far) from perfection.

Comment: @Servy still boring you, but the arguments for StringConvert are nullable double or nullable decimal, not just double or decimal. You can treat this way double, decimal, double?, decimal?, int, and int? (well everything which is convertible to a nullable double or a nullable decimal, in fact). But even with that, your code will break if we choose to add a DateTime property... (I never found a really elegant way to treat that problem, without using some Assertions on accepted types, by the way)

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus The fact that the problem isn't really solvable is exactly why I explain in my answer that you shouldn't try to generate the selectors dynamically, as it simply isn't solvable in the general case.  One needs to manually indicate what fields should be searched, and how.

Comment: @Servy yes, or you may just accept (with reflection) the types that you know you CAN treat. So an array of accepted types, for example, and `.GetProperties.Where(m => <acceptedTypeArray>.Contains(m.PropertyType);` But I agree.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus Although that still leaves you with the problem of silently ignoring a bunch of fields.  In my eyes that overload is for the special case where you know everything either is a string or is another supported type, and if not you shouldn't be touching that overload.  Having it complain *loudly* when it doesn't work at least prevents the programmer form having expectations that the code doesn't meet.